# Feature Selection using PSM

Tags: feature-selection

A colleague has proposed using propensity score matching to do feature selection prior to building a model to predict a binary outcome.

There are 28 variables to select the best predictors from.  He proposes iterating 28 times, matching cases on the outcome (success/failure) leaving one variable out each time.  At each iteration mean difference tests are conducted on the omitted variable to see if that variable is still meaningful to a difference in the outcome beyond chance. He says that variables that are estimated to have a mean difference are likely valuable to predicting our outcome.

I have never seen this approach to feature selection so am wondering if it is valid.